# How to set default variable for a single command with env variables?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, xdg

I need to override default browser for single process. This process starts manually from npm scripts. To achieve this programmatically, I decided to override `BROWSER` environment variable right before the script. But it does not work. It steal opens system wide default browser. I tried with `xdg-open`, but it is not working too.

To be short, I want the following command open given URL in provided browser, not in default one.

```bsh
BROWSER='path to desired browser' xdg-open 'any url'
```

P.S.: Just to tell a little bit more about my problem. I am using Firefox as the default browser an all my machines, and got quite used to it. But recently, debugging one web application, I realized that some break ponts were not used by Firefox dev tools. I installed Chromium, and its debugger worked as expected. I use storybook for development, and would like to open it in Chromium, while using Firefox as default variable for the regular everyday use.

Comment: what you wrote is the official way to do it (at least from bash). have you tried it ? what  goes wrong ?

Comment: Well, it simply opens system wide default browser, not the one i pass in. Should I provide some information about my system? I am using Manjaro with KDE.

Comment: If it is official way, than probably my environment configured wrongly, so I probably have to reconfigure it somehow.

Comment: The variable is not required to work with any command. If the command is not design to obey `BROWSER` then it will ignore `BROWSER`. In my Kubuntu `xdg-open` seems to ignore `BROWSER` and I cannot (yet?) find the documentation that says it should obey. Can you tell what relevant command(s) your npm scripts or the "single process" use? The one(s) that actually start the default browser? Is it `xdg-open`? A wrapper script over this command may be a possibility; a wrapper script over Firefox may be a possibility. Is `PATH` respected or are full paths hardcoded? Do you have root access?

Comment: I understand, that a program can simply ignore environment, but  `BROWSER` env variable was mentioned [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables). I also saw other examples of using this variables.
The command I want to launch is just a [start-storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/cli-options/), it can be installed with npm. As you can see, it does not support browser selection.I do not know, how does it get information about my default browser, but it do, somehow. I think handling error with `xdg-open` will solve my main issue.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). The answer to the title is "exactly how you did". You did set the variable for the command. Then the command simply and by design paid no attention to the variable. How about `start-storybook --ci` (skip interactive prompts, don't open browser)? If skipping interactive prompts is OK then you can probably build a script that will run `start-storybook --ci` and Chromium in two separate steps. I'm not posting an answer because I did not tested this.

Comment: I tested it, it worked. Here is my code
`start-storybook --config-dir storybook_configs --static-dir story_assets --ci --port 8080 && env-cmd --use-shell '$BROWSER' http://localhost:8080`
I also have local file `.env` with following content `BROWSER = /usr/bin/chromium`.

Comment: 1) dot not put space arround `=` when assigning a variable, 2) do not use signle quote `'` use double instead `"`.

Comment: 1) .env file for env-cmd utilite can handle spaces around `=`, it is not bash
2) Don't use double quotes, use single quotes! In my case I want env-cmd to do the variables expansion, not the my current terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar, but not limited to situations that respected `$BROWSER`, as `xdg-open` would frequently use the wrong browser profile.

Here is a workaround with the following components:

- A script that loads the `BROWSER` variable and launches the correct browser.
- An override for current default `.desktop` profile by copying it to the `~/.local/share/applications` directory.
- Change the `Exec` statements in the `.desktop` file to use the custom script.
- Set the `BROWSER` variable to a sane default in the login shell to have a fallback.

### Step-by-step

I added a script to my `~/bin` directory called `custom-browser` that looks like:

```
$BROWSER "$@"
```

Second, find the current `.desktop` profile with:

```
xdg-settings get default-web-browser
```

That gave me `firefox.desktop`, which I copied to my user home directory:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

I modified the `Exec` statements in `~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop` to launch `/home/{user}/bin/custom-browser`.

Now, I can use:

```
BROWSER='chromium' xdg-open 'https://startpage.com'
BROWSER='firefox' xdg-open 'https://startpage.com'
```

To open different browsers based on the `BROWSER` variable.
Hope this helps you in some way.

### My usage

I use [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/)[1] to set the `BROWSER` variable based on the directory, for example, work directories use a work profile for my browser.

Another is that I launch apps with `BROWSER=hardened-firefox signal-desktop` to force the app to open links with a specific browser.

### Notes

- The script is necessary because the `.desktop` file does not load environment variables, so adding `Exec=$BROWSER %u` directly does not work.
- It is possible to set the fallback for `BROWSER` in the script instead of the login shell.
- It is possible to write a custom `.desktop` file and changing the default with `xdg-settings`/`xdg-mime` instead of overriding the default; I found it easier to get it "right" with the override.
- If using browsers that do not use the URL as the first positional parameter, a custom `.desktop` and dealing with that in the script may be easier.
- If the `.desktop` profile is not in `/usr/share/applications`, or the override in `$HOME/.local/share/applications` does not work, try the [alternative paths](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/latest/ar01s02.html)[2] or refer to your distribution's documentation.

### Links

1. https://direnv.net/
2. https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/latest/ar01s02.html

Answer (score -2):

`export BROWSER='path to desired browser' && xdg-open 'any url'` should dothe trick.

Comment: It does not work(

Comment: The only difference from what the OP has already tried (`BROWSER='path to desired browser' xdg-open 'any url'`) is you change the variable also in the current execution environment. How can it help?

Comment: Because the way some forkers work (I don't know if xdg-open is one of them): Some create a new environment (hence the `export`) and only then resolve the target to `execve` it.

Comment: I don't understand what difference it makes here. I think `xdg-open` has no simple way to tell if the variable is in the environment of its parent process (here: the shell); and it has absolutely no reason to care. It knows its own environment and `BROWSER` will be there, regardless if the code used is yours or the OP's. What am I missing?

Comment: Many forkers (which might include `xdg-open`) fork first, then **reset their environment** then evaluate and `execve`